# How to find out if a string contains all characters in a set of characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-group

I have been struggling with a regex pattern to find out if a string contains all characters in a set of characters.
e.g I want to test if "sheena" contains **esnh**, I should get a match but if I want to test if "sheena" contains **esnk**, I should not get a match because there exist no **k** in "sheena" even thought **esn** exists.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem just use the `every` method.

```js
const matchString = (str, matcher) => [...matcher].every(n => str.includes(n));
console.log(matchString('sheena', 'eshn'));
console.log(matchString('sheena', 'eshk'));
```